# How to compile a C program that includes `math.h` using vscode code-runner extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

Is there a way to compile a C program that includes `math.h` using the vscode `code-runner` extension? I know that the program can be compiled by appending `-lm` option at the end of the `gcc` command if I compile it in the terminal. The thing is I do not want to compile the program from the terminal.

As a workaround, I tried to change `"code-runner.executorMapByFileExtension"` as follows.

```
"code-runner.executorMapByFileExtension" : {
   ".c": "cd $dir && gcc $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt -lm && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt"
}
```

Note `-lm` option appended. But I could not get it done because the command to compile the program is not overwritten?

Any ideas to solve this problem are appreciated.

Edit: Forgot to say that I am on linux.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to figure out a way to load the `math.h` file in Visual Studio Code, either. It seems that there is no choice but to build from the terminal so that you can pass the `-lm` switch.

Answer (score 0):

In VS Code with the Code Runner extension installed, go to File > Preferences > Settings. Type into the search bar "Code Runner". Scroll down until you see the option titled "Code-runner: Executor Map". Click on the "Edit in settings.json" link. Make sure you are looking at the options under "code-runner.executorMap" and look for the key, value pair for "c". You should see something similar to "cd $dir && gcc $fileName -o ...".
All you need to do is insert the "-lm" into that statement (i.e. "cd $dir && gcc $fileName -lm -o ..."). Every time you build and run your C code using Code Runner, you should be able to have the math.h libary linked.